# How Can I Drop ALL Constraints From a Database?

Tags: mysql

The constraints from the database design i'm using are limiting my updates and I want to get rid of all of them. Is there a way to DROP ALL CONSTRAINTS from ALL tables at once? I tried the query below without success as I do not know what`s information_schema... I'm not using any schema per se... Everything is created in phpmyAdmin...

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE="FOREIGN KEY"
```

Comment: Do you really want to drop them, or just disable constraint checking temporarily?

Comment: Soounds like a horrible idea

Comment: @Barmar: I really do want to drop all of them... I don't even use them..

Comment: @e4c5: Well I didn't design the tables... Someone landed the design to me so that development would be faster... But turns out I'm just using his tables not his DESIGN... His design is limiting me a LOT and I have been adding my own columns for that matter but now I realize there are lots of them and I'm wasting a lot of time with that issue

Comment: If it's a one time thing, just dump your schema into a text editor, delete a bunch of stuff that doesn't matter, and search/replace the rest. Voila.

Comment: If the given design doesn't match your requirements, you should take the time to make a completely new design.

Comment: Better still, you should take the time to understand why the constraints are there and why your updates are not correct according to them.

Comment: I am looking for the same functionality. `select * from information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS;`  shows all constraint in the server. Maybe a function is the solution. [Found this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/730b7082-2ceb-49e2-a052-68e6b2c25bb5/how-to-delete-all-foreign-keys-in-a-database?forum=databasedesign) ...but on MSSQLServer :/)

Comment: @iqbal_cs: yeah well that's something to think about. I am non longer in need to do so. I have solved the issue. Turns out it had nothing to do with the foreign key but more to do with my query. In order to keep database intact I just added another column so that it behave like I want. Much less of a headache. Works for me.